Solve a system of equations
I am trying to solve the following system of equations:
$$ \alpha + \beta + \gamma = - \frac{P}{Q} $$
$$ \alpha \gamma + \beta \gamma + \alpha \beta = 0 $$
$$ \alpha \beta \gamma = - \frac{C}{Q} $$
Where $P$, $C$ and $Q$ are positive. To do this, I was guided by the following example that I found:
$$ \begin{array}{rr}
\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta=0 & \left(\frac{1}{b_o^2}+C\right)=(\beta+\alpha)(\delta+\gamma)+\gamma \delta+\alpha \beta \\
\alpha \beta \gamma \delta=\frac{C}{b_o^2} & \alpha \beta \delta+\alpha \beta \gamma+\beta \gamma \delta+\alpha \gamma \delta=0
\end{array} $$
where I should get:
$$ \alpha=-\sqrt{C}, \quad \beta=-\frac{1}{b_o}, \quad \gamma=\frac{1}{b_o}, \quad \delta=\sqrt{C}$$
but I don't get that value for the constants. What I wrote was:
Solve[{\[Alpha] + \[Beta] + \[Gamma] + \[Delta] == 
   0; (\[Beta] + \[Alpha]) (\[Delta] + \[Gamma]) + \[Gamma]*\[Delta] \
+ \[Alpha]*\[Beta] == 
   1/(Subscript[b, 0])^2 + C; \[Alpha]*\[Beta]*\[Gamma]*\[Delta] == 
   CC/(Subscript[b, 
    0])^2; \[Alpha]*\[Beta]*\[Delta] + \[Alpha]*\[Beta]*\[Gamma] + \
\[Beta]*\[Gamma]*\[Delta] + \[Alpha]*\[Gamma]*\[Delta] == 
   0}, {\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma], \[Delta]}]


What is my mistake? Could someone guide me for this example or how to apply it to the first one? Sorry if the question is too basic.

This is strange, First you give 3 equations, then solve something completely different. Why not just solve the equations you want to solve?   https://i.sstatic.net/CbBbiPbr.png  and better not to use C and not use subscripted variables.

Also, your list of equations  should be separated by commas and not semicolons

@Nasser I tried to start with the second system of equations as a practice but I found that I couldn't find the solutions I should for the constants. I also tried to solve the first system of equations but I found the same thing as you and I thought I was wrong because, honestly, I wasn't expecting such complicated solutions

If I try to check the solution to the example problem {\[Alpha]+\[Beta]+\[Gamma]+\[Delta]==0,(\[Beta]+\[Alpha])(\[Delta]+\[Gamma])+\[Gamma]*\[Delta]+\[Alpha]*\[Beta]==1/ (Subscript[b,0])^2+CapC,\[Alpha]*\[Beta]*\[Gamma]*\[Delta]==CapC/(Subscript[b,0] )^2,\[Alpha]*\[Beta]*\[Delta]+\[Alpha]*\[Beta]*\[Gamma]+\[Beta]*\[Gamma]*\[Delta]+\[Alpha]*\[Gamma]*\[Delta]==0}/.{\[Alpha]->-Sqrt[CapC],\[Beta]->-1/Subscript[b,0],\[Gamma]->1/Subscript[b,0],\[Delta]->Sqrt[CapC]}//Simplify then I get {True, 2*(CapC + Subscript[b, 0]^(-2)) == 0, True, True} so I or the post has an error in 2nd eqn.

I wasn't expecting such complicated solutions  the equations are non linear with respect to unknowns, so the solution being complicated could be expected.

Seems like a complicated way to solve a cubic.

According to the Vieta's formulas, in the first case the unknowns are roots of
Reduce[z^3 + P/Q*z^2 + C/Q == 0, z] // ToRadicals


Q != 0 && (z ==  1/3 (-(P/Q) + (2^(1/3) P^2)/( Q (-2 P^3 - 27 C Q^2 +  3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[4 C P^3 Q^2 + 27 C^2 Q^4])^( 1/3)) + (-2 P^3 - 27 C Q^2 +  3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[4 C P^3 Q^2 + 27 C^2 Q^4])^(1/3)/( 2^(1/3) Q)) ||  z == -(P/(3 Q)) - ((1 + I Sqrt[3]) P^2)/( 3 2^(2/3) Q (-2 P^3 - 27 C Q^2 +  3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[4 C P^3 Q^2 + 27 C^2 Q^4])^( 1/3)) - ((1 - I Sqrt[3]) (-2 P^3 - 27 C Q^2 +  3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[4 C P^3 Q^2 + 27 C^2 Q^4])^(1/3))/( 6 2^(1/3) Q) ||  z == -(P/(3 Q)) - ((1 - I Sqrt[3]) P^2)/( 3 2^(2/3) Q (-2 P^3 - 27 C Q^2 +  3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[4 C P^3 Q^2 + 27 C^2 Q^4])^( 1/3)) - ((1 + I Sqrt[3]) (-2 P^3 - 27 C Q^2 +  3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[4 C P^3 Q^2 + 27 C^2 Q^4])^(1/3))/(6 2^(1/3) Q) )

and in the second case the unknowns are the roots
Reduce[z^4 - (1/b0^2 + C)*z^2 + C/b0^2 == 0, z] // ToRadicals


((z == -Sqrt[C] || z == Sqrt[C]) && b0 != 0) || (b0 != 0 &&  z == -(1/b0)) || (b0 != 0 && z == 1/b0)

Addition.  There likely is a typo in the formulation of the second system. As written in the question, the unknowns are the roots of
Reduce[z^4 + (1/b0^2 + C)*z^2 + C/b0^2 == 0, z] // ToRadicals


((z == -I Sqrt[C] || z == I Sqrt[C]) &&  b0 != 0) || (b0 != 0 && (z == -(I/b0) || z == I/b0))

This differs from the suggested solution. I should be more careful.
